# What is the maximum AC possible without using magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, armor-class

What is the maximum AC a PC can acquire without the use of magic items?

Allowed content are feats, spells, and temporary effects - but not effects from allies, magical items, or UA content.

Comment: You can't use Bladesong with a shield. And since you are not wearing armor you can't use Defense from fighter either.

Comment: To confirm: You are saying no magic items, but magical buffs are okay?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, but it's definitely not clear in what's allowed to determine AC (buffs, temporary abilities, unearthed arcana, feats, etc.)

Comment: Hey, sorry I just got this- yes I'm allowing feats, spells, temporary effects,- but no UA material or allied help.

Comment: You should still include the bit on what you allow (feats, etc.)

Comment: I rolled the question back to how you got your best AC result and made the question hopefully a little bit more clear. Are you dead set on this multiclassed build? or will you accept any character progression?

Comment: Defensive Duelist only adds +6 at most you have it going from 25 to 33 which is +8? Also Evasive Foot work only works on Opportunity Attacks https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80531/how-long-does-the-battlemasters-evasive-footwork-last, to limited IMO to warrant being added to actual AC. Yet another problem is there is no Defensive Footwork it's Defensive Flourish you want.

Comment: It may also help to move your 'answer' out of the question and into the answers. Post your question as a stand-alone and provide your answer as an option below.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a shield with the Bladesong, dropping you to 34+1d10+1d8; however, by holding a second weapon in your off hand you can take the Dual Wielder feat, adding another 1AC. The Fighter's Defense style doesn't work either (no armour), so you're down another point.

We can also get behind three quarters cover, adding an extra 5, bringing us to 39+1d10+1d8.

Finally, let's drop three levels of Bladesinger and five of Bard, replacing them with Hunter Ranger 7/Cleric 1. The loss of Haste is replaced with the Cleric's Shield of Faith; the Bard drops to a d8, but in exchange we can get Multiattack Defense, which gives us +4 to AC versus a creature who's already hit us.

Final total: **43+2d8**

Comment: If you're using unarmored defense, then how are you using Forge Cleric to buff your armor?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the armor blessed by a Forge Cleric be considered a "magic item" , which OP doesn't want?

Comment: Forge Cleric armour is a magic item for the purpose of game effects, but I'd argue that the purpose of requesting 'no magical items' is more for the purpose of blocking owned magic items, rather than class abilities. That said, Ben's point stands and I've removed it (as well as the bit of UA I was using, as per updated question).

Comment: This needs to be reworked a little, or at least reframed, after the answery-bit was taken out of the question.