# How does Evasive Footwork work for characters that can fly?

Tags: flight, battle-master

If you playing a flying character, such as a tiefling, and you don't logically stop moving to make your attack, does the AC bonus end since you haven't actually stopped moving, even to make your attack.  I think a strict interpretation of the combat rules says yes, correct?  But does that make sense?

Comment: Related: "[How long does the AC increase from the Battle Master fighter's Evasive Footwork maneuver last?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80531)"

Comment: I assume this is about the fifth edition of Dungeons & Dragons? If so, leaving a comment affirming this or editing in the [tag:dnd-5e] tag would help us to better answer your question. That all said, hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and feel free to leave a comment here or visit the [help] for further guidance. Best of luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Could you clarify which game and edition this is for?

Comment: As a note to folks voting to close due to lack of a system, please see this meta post which details our revised protocols regarding the [Don't Guess the System policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/what-should-i-do-when-a-question-does-not-specify-the-game-system-being-used?cb=1).

Comment: @Pyrotechnical "One user may think they have a questions narrowed down to two systems, and one user may think the question should be closed for "needs details or clarity". **This second user is free to vote for closure on the question**, and the community will work it out as we do with all questions that are put up for closure review."

Answer (score 3):

[dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)

#### Assuming this is about the fifth edition of Dungeons & Dragons: Attacks made by flying creatures break up their movement the same as any other creature so the benefit of Evasive Footwork ends

The Battle Master Fighter's Evasive Footwork Maneuver states:

> When you move, you can expend one superiority die, rolling the die and adding the number rolled to your AC until you stop moving.

Note, this AC benefit lasts *until you stop moving* and we already have a question on what exactly this means:

- [How long does the AC increase from the Battle Master fighter's Evasive Footwork maneuver last?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80531)

The [highest-scoring answer there](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80535) states:

> [...] If you make an attack, it "breaks up your move" (PHB 190), ending the bonus [...]

Thus, making an attack breaks up your movement and ends the bonus. Flying creatures actually don't change this at all; the general rules on ["Breaking Up Your Move"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BreakingUpYourMove) state:

> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action. For example, if you have a speed of 30 feet, you can move 10 feet, take your action, and then move 20 feet. [...]

Thus, whenever you take an action in the middle of your movement you *are* breaking up your move, the [rules on flying movements](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#FlyingMovement) never change this fact:

> Flying creatures enjoy many benefits of mobility, but they must also deal with the danger of falling. If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as by the fly spell.

Thus, when a flying creature moves 10 feet and then makes an attack they *have* broken up their move and would stop benefitting from Evasive Footwork. There simply aren't any rules stating otherwise.

---

#### Why I have assumed this is about 5e D&D

1. Tieflings are a D&D creature.
2. The [battle-master](/questions/tagged/battle-master) tag's description is this:

> The Battle Master is a fighter subclass in Dungeons & Dragons 5th edition (published in the Player's Handbook), and has the ability to use a number of different combat maneuvers in battle.

3. Evasive Footwork is the name of one of the Maneuvers that the Battle Master Fighter gets in 5e D&D.
4. The Evasive Footwork Maneuver found in 5e D&D grants an AC bonus that ends when you stop moving, just as the OP describes.
5. There is a variant Tiefling, the Winged Tiefling, that flies.

Comment: Please don't answer if you are not sure what game and edition question is about. And if you are sure, please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mołot That is *not* what [the recent guidance](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11723) states: "If you take a shot at figuring out the system and post an answer, **and your system assumption turns out to be incorrect**, your answer will be deleted. [...] The second risk element here deals with question closure. [...] If you choose to answer such a question, you are assuming the risk that the question may end up closed before you finish writing your answer. This is the cost of doing business with underspecified questions."

Comment: @Mołot "When a question could feasibly concern any of two or more systems, instead of tagging the question, we should instead state the system in the answer. Ideally, this would be a brief explanation that the answer is only applicable to the one particular system. We would like to avoid having a user misunderstand this and think an answer for one system applies to a different system. Just be clear about what game your answer applies to." This *explicitly* condones answering when unsure, and honestly, I *am* quite sure, I'm just not gonna start a tag editing war since people clearly disagree